# How to use setrequired() in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am pretty new to google apps script, since the google form cannot do the conditional required function, i will need to modify the form myself. I found this code in the google apps script website and i tried to play around with it to kind of test out if i will be able to achieve what i want.
What do i want to achieve:

1. For 'Do you prefer cats or dogs?' question, if the user chose Cats, the 'Rate your interests' question will be automatically set to required.

What did i get from the codes i have:

1. The if statement did not work as expected. 'Rate your interests' question is set to required regardless of the if statement conditions.

Below are the codes:

```
function myfunction(){
var form = FormApp.create('New Form');
var item = form.addCheckboxItem();
item.setTitle('What condiments would you like on your hot dog?');
item.setChoices([
    item.createChoice('Ketchup'),
    item.createChoice('Mustard'),
    item.createChoice('Relish')
]);
var a= form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
.setTitle('Do you prefer cats or dogs?')
.setChoiceValues(['Cats','Dogs'])
.showOtherOption(true);
form.addPageBreakItem()
.setTitle('Getting to know you');
form.addDateItem()
.setTitle('When were you born?');
var b= form.addGridItem()
.setTitle('Rate your interests')
.setRows(['Cars', 'Computers', 'Celebrities'])
.setColumns(['Boring', 'So-so', 'Interesting']);
if (a != null){
b= b.setRequired(true);
}

Logger.log('Published URL: ' + form.getPublishedUrl());
Logger.log('Editor URL: ' + form.getEditUrl());
}
```

Comment: You'll need to roll your own html form, with client-side JavaScript to display the right questions based on previous answers, and validation on both client and server to ensure that the questions that need to be answered have been answered. Apps Script for Google Forms is 100% incapable of doing this for you.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your if statement: Variable "a" will not be null as you have just set a value to variable A.

You have to remember you are creating a form, think of this as a once off process. This script will not be running when the user is submitting their response to you form.

I can see what you are trying to achieve here, sadly it is not possible with the code above.

I could possible recommend setting Do you prefer cats or dogs as a required question, and then going to a different section based on the answer.

E.G I like cats, go to section 2 of the form. I like dogs, go to section 3 of the form. (See pic for example.)[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am trying to avoid using this method as the actual form that i want to create have pretty much questions(Item requesting form) and if i use this method, it will be frustrating for the user to have to chose next till it reaches their desired items.

Comment: In the past I was required to build something similar to what you are trying to do. Unfortunately with Google Forms it is just not possible. Google Forms is great for capturing information, but it is very limited in what it can do. Trying to incorporate workflow settings into it can be a real PITA. I would recommend looking into Web Forms as an alternative. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/what-is-web-forms

Comment: i change the code to                                                   
if (a == 'Cats'){
    b= b.setRequired(true);
  }                                                                                                          However, it did not work.

Comment: Yes, it will set b to be required irregardless. You will realise that this is once off however. In other words, when you user is submitting a response to the form it will be set to required regardless of what they have selected in a.

Comment: i tried using web forms but i'm having the same problem.

Comment: I've got no experience in using web forms. It is what was advised to me when I asked a senior team member questions similar to yours. If you do ever find a solution to the problem I would ask that you message me with the solution. Alternatively accept that Google Forms is limited in what it can do and use the above method as a solution. (Please mark as a solution if you are okay with this.)